# Java constant expression related code optimization on compile

Tags: java

Here is a simple question about Java compile optimisation.

Is

```
final int CONSTANT_NUMBER="Foo Bar".length();
```

equal to

```
final int CONSTANT_NUMBER=7;
```

on compiling code or generally in performance aspect?

Comment: The compiling code and the performance aren't equal.

Comment: Yeah of course, but one strongly affects the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the java compiler doesn't evaluate `"Foo Bar".length()` at compile time.

Consider these classes

```
public class ConstantCheck {

    final int CONSTANT_NUMBER = "Foo Bar".length();
}
```

and

```
public class ConstantCheck {

    final int CONSTANT_NUMBER = 7;
}
```

Using `javap -v` on the compiled `.class` file you can see, that the `.length()` call is kept:

The former results in

```
...

  final int CONSTANT_NUMBER;
    descriptor: I
    flags: ACC_FINAL

  public text.ConstantCheck();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: ldc           #2                  // String Foo Bar
         7: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
        10: putfield      #4                  // Field CONSTANT_NUMBER:I
        13: return
...
```

the latter in

```
...

  final int CONSTANT_NUMBER;
    descriptor: I
    flags: ACC_FINAL
    ConstantValue: int 7

  public text.ConstantCheck();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0
         5: bipush        7
         7: putfield      #2                  // Field CONSTANT_NUMBER:I
        10: return
    ....
```

In the first case the `.length` call is present

```
7: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/String.length:()I
```

in the second case it's just a constant that is written to the field

```
5: bipush        7
7: putfield      #2                  // Field CONSTANT_NUMBER:I
```

Comment: Yeah it's unfortunate to see that. I thought compilers would be able to detect code like that.

Answer (score 1):

From compiling, definitely second is going to be a little faster, as it first has a method call. However, machines these days are way too fast for this to be noticeable or significant.

For performance - Modern compilers should be smart to see that "Foo Bar" is a constant and should replace the expression to length. If however, you change the line to be a variable, then you may be able to fool the compiler to call the method every time, there by making 1st slightly faster if run in a big loop.

I tested this by making them run in a big loop and second method gave slightly better performance. Guess my compiler isn't smart enough to replace the method call with a constant.

So short answer , performance wise, direct int is better than method call on my machine, but it may differ on a different compiler.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for! :D